# Unused Local Variable the variable is overwritten immediately

Tags: php

```
<?php
/*FInd fifth_number - private method*/

  function get_number_root($root) {
      switch($root) {
          case 'A':
              $number = 1;
              break;
          case 'A#':
              $number = 2;
              break;
          case 'Bb':
              $number = 2;
              break;
          case 'B':
              $number = 3;
              break;
          case 'C':
              $number = 4;
              break;
          case 'C#':
              $number = 5;
              break;
          case 'Db':
              $number = 5;
              break;
          case 'D':
              $number = 6;
              break;
          case 'D#':
              $number = 7;
              break;
          case 'Eb':
              $number = 7;
              break;
          case 'E':
              $number = 8;
              break;
          case 'F':
              $number = 9;
              break;
          case 'F#':
              $number = 10;
              break;
          case 'G':
              $number = 11;
              break;
          case 'G#':
              $number = 12;
              break;
          case 'Ab':
              $number = 12;
              break;
          default:
              die('error');
              return $number;
      }

      $number = get_number_root($_POST['root']);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish, so in order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it adds a little **context** to help clarify your **intent**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: This comment was posted 2 years ago. I would like to delete this question. I don't think it is a good contribution to this website. However, I was banned from asking questions, and I do not want to risk losing the ability to ask questions. Would it be OK to delete this question? I answered my first question today and if you look at it those are the types of contributions I plan to make to this site.

Comment: @bkabbott Likely not, because it already has an accepted answer. See [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) for an explanation. You can always request your name be [dissociated from the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0) but abusing this feature will lead to a suspension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens since you have not used the `$number` variable for any purpose in your code.
So it is unused.
Also since you are calling  `$number = get_number_root($_POST['root']);` inside the same method, right after switch case statement, number overwritten by calling the method.
to overcome this write function to return number and call that function in a different method.
Check the below example

```
   function get_number_root($root) {
        switch($root) {
            case 'A':
                $number = 1;
                break;
            case 'A#':
                $number = 2;
                break;
            case 'Bb':
                $number = 2;
                break;
            case 'B':
                $number = 3;
                break;
            case 'C':
                $number = 4;
                break;
            case 'C#':
                $number = 5;
                break;
            case 'Db':
                $number = 5;
                break;
            case 'D':
                $number = 6;
                break;
            case 'D#':
                $number = 7;
                break;
            case 'Eb':
                $number = 7;
                break;
            case 'E':
                $number = 8;
                break;
            case 'F':
                $number = 9;
                break;
            case 'F#':
                $number = 10;
                break;
            case 'G':
                $number = 11;
                break;
            case 'G#':
                $number = 12;
                break;
            case 'Ab':
                $number = 12;
                break;
            default:
                die('error');
        }
       return $number;

    }

function getNumberAccordingToRoot(){
     $number = get_number_root($_POST['root']);
//Do the necessaries to $number here
}
```